# Is PHPWord suitable for direct mail?

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge, phpword, docx-mailmerge

Is PHPWord suitable for direct mail? (also named Mail Merge in MS Office Word)

Here is the process I want to automat:

.docx documents are provided to the application. They are formatted for direct mail with fixed parts and a collection of merge fields.

For each document, the application will search for the data in several databases, then create the custom documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found this

http://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html

Efficient but does not use native word merge fields.

According to me, it's a lack because we are forced to retouch already existing standard documents.