# Can you use Word content control fields as placeholders in PHPWord templates natively?

Tags: php, phpword

We are currently using a custom solution for parsing Word document templates which replaces Word content control fields (text fields, check boxes, etc.) with custom values.

We would like to accomplish this with PHPWord, but it [looks like the only type of placeholders it supports are strings](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html) like `${placeholder_name}`.

The closest existing post I can find refers to Mail Merge and isn't promising: [Is PHPWord suitable for direct mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561739/is-phpword-suitable-for-direct-mail)

Comment: Hi, you should probably describe a more concrete need, and what you have tried to fulfill this need. For example : since PHPWord claims to be able to generate almost any file content, I would be tempted to answer "yes it can do it". Can you try to reformulate your question, in a format more suitable to Stackoverflow Q&A ? see [SO guidelines to good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: btw : it's a "ouiche"

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @LeGEC! I've updated my post after reviewing the link you posted.